# Sybase round not working as expected

Tags: rounding, sybase, isql

Below is my scenario. We are retrieving data from Sybase. We are using putty to achieve this since we do not have direct access to Sybase. From the inner query, i am getting value as 6.500000 for a metric. But in the outer query, when i apply Round function to this metric , it is becoming 6 instead of 7. Please help on this issue!

Below is my Inner query and the complete query. Have attached the data also for reference.

Inner Query

```
SELECT D.Col1,A.Col2,C.Col3,
SUM ( C.net_td_cnt ) AS td_cnt
FROM Tab1 A,Tab2 B,Tab3 C,Tab4 D
WHERE (A.Tab1 =B.Tab1 AND B.Tab2=C.yld_loc_cd AND D.Tab1=A.Tab1)
AND (D.Col1 IN ('Fil1') and A.Col2='Fil2'
AND ((C.Col3 BETWEEN 'Jul 6 2016' AND 'Jul 6 2016') OR 
(C.Col3 BETWEEN 'Jul    6 2016' AND 'Jul 6 2016')))
GROUP BY D.Col1,A.Col2,C.Col3
UNION
SELECT C.Col1,A.Col2,D.Col3,
SUM ( D.net_td_cnt ) AS td_cnt
FROM Tab1 A,Tab2 B,Tab4 C,Tab5 D
WHERE ( A.Tab1 =B.Tab1 AND C.Tab1=A.Tab1 AND B.Tab2 =D.yld_loc_cd )
AND ( C.Col1 IN ('Fil1') and A.Col2='Fil2' 
AND (D.Col3 BETWEEN 'Jul 6 2016' AND 'Jul 6 2016') )
GROUP BY C.Col1,A.Col2,D.Col3
```

Output:
    Col1    |Col2   |Col3               |td_cnt
    Fil1    |Fil2   |Jul  6 2016 12:00AM    |6.500000

Full Query

```
SELECT A.Col1,A.Col2,A.Col3,
ROUND(A.td_cnt,0)  AS td_cnt
FROM
(SELECT D.Col1,A.Col2,C.Col3,
SUM ( C.net_td_cnt ) AS td_cnt
FROM Tab1 A,Tab2 B,Tab3 C,Tab4 D
WHERE (A.Tab1 =B.Tab1 AND B.Tab2=C.yld_loc_cd AND D.Tab1=A.Tab1)
AND (D.Col1 IN ('Fil1') and A.Col2='Fil2'
AND ((C.Col3 BETWEEN 'Jul 6 2016' AND 'Jul 6 2016') OR 
(C.Col3 BETWEEN 'Jul    6 2016' AND 'Jul 6 2016')))
GROUP BY D.Col1,A.Col2,C.Col3
UNION
SELECT C.Col1,A.Col2,D.Col3,
SUM ( D.net_td_cnt ) AS td_cnt
FROM Tab1 A,Tab2 B,Tab4 C,Tab5 D
WHERE ( A.Tab1 =B.Tab1 AND C.Tab1=A.Tab1 AND B.Tab2 =D.yld_loc_cd )
AND ( C.Col1 IN ('Cent') and A.Col2='Fil2' 
AND (D.Col3 BETWEEN 'Jul 6 2016' AND 'Jul 6 2016') )
GROUP BY C.Col1,A.Col2,D.Col3
) A ORDER BY A.Col3
```

Output:
    Col1    |Col2   |Col3               |td_cnt
    Fil1    |Fil2   |Jul  6 2016 12:00AM    |6

Answer (score 0):

select round(6.500000,0) returns 7 in various versions of sybase ASE and IQ, what is your product version? Please run

select @@version

Kimon